# Ignore empty attribute in SOAP Response in Java

Tags: java, exception, soap, axis

I'm trying to ignore empty attributes from a SOAP response. If the empty attributes are decimal or string for example, nothing happens, but with dateTime attributes my Java code runs this exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid
> date/time

Here is a piece of the xsd specification file:

```
<element name="creationDate" type="dateTime" db:type="DATE" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
```

And here the empty attribute in response

```
<ns3:creationDate/>
```

My project use Java 11 and Apache Axis 1.4.

Is there a way to ignore the empty attributes(or another solution to get the response correctly without an exception) considering that I don't have access to the SOAP service to modify it, I can only consume it.

Comment: The service you are calling seems broken. The field is marked as nillable in the WSDL and based on the response it does indeed look like it's nil, but it should be `<ns3:creationDate nil="true" />`  not just `<ns3:creationDate/>`. Have you generated you client code with Axis? How does the code for the creation date field look like? (BTW, Axis is rather old. Are you using it from legacy code?)

Comment: Finally it was a service bug. The SOAP service owner fixed it to send only attributes with values in response and that solved my problem. However I'm interested in what you said about Axis is rather old.  What more modern solution could I use in future projects that involve consume SOAP services?

Comment: You could use Axis2 for example. Apache CXF is another popular option.